# How do you interpret "explained" coefficients in Blinder-Oaxaca decomposition with considerable negative values?

Tags: regression, econometrics, regression-coefficients

For illustrative purposes, consider the example given on p. 473 of [Jann (2008)](https://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=st0151). However, instead of the difference and coefficients noted, let's assume the difference and coefficients were the following:

Difference: 0.20

Explained

- educ: 0.15
- exp_ten: 0.15
- isco: -0.15
- Total: 0.15

How would you properly describe these results? It seems odd to say that educ and exp_ten each individually accounted for 100% of the explained part of the outcome differential, but that would seem to be consistent with Jann's interpretation when no considerable negative coefficient was present:

> Differences in education and combined differences in experience and
>   tenure each account for about half the explained part of the outcome
>   differential, whereas occupational segregation based on the nine major
>   groups of the International Standard Classification of Occupations
>   (ISCO-88) does not seem to matter much.

Here's the screenshot of the Stata output from Jann's example on p. 473:
[image: Jann 2008 Stata output (p. 473)]